Sample a number x uniformly from $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ using two fair coin flips with a finite, deterministic number of steps
I want to randomly choose one of the numbers 1, 2 and 3 where they have the same probability.
One way of doing this would be to interpret the coin flip result as a binary number, repeating the flip if the result is the number 0.
I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this with a single flip of both coins.
I'd appreciate it if someone could share some relevant sources related to this.
Thanks!

"...with a single flip of both coins..." : hard to visualize a solution, since $~2^2~$ is relatively prime to $~3.$

You can't do it with any deterministic number of steps because $3$ does not divide any $2^n$.  With lots of steps the probability you have not solved the problem gets very small, but never hits $0$

I think the number of steps in your first solution (using binary digits) is a Geometrically distributed random variable, which does not satisfy the condition of deterministic number of steps stated in the title.
